# Sparkle Error: The update is improperly signed

Tags: macos, cocoa, sparkle

I am using sparkle for software update. I signed my app with Apple developer certificate and uploaded the build. Then I tried to update by calling 'checkForUpdates:' method. But I am getting an error saying "Update is not properly signed". What might be the reason? Did I miss anything?

Comment: It's hard to say without any other information. If your app is meant to be public, is it possible for you to provide your appcast url / update url? On top of the head, I would say there is a problem with the appcast, or an openssl version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to review the tips about how to codesign properly for Sparkle here:
https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/216

Specifically, sign all binaries and frameworks, and do so with the proper codesign arguments.